# Dynamic click event on PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting a list of pictures from a directory and storing the filenames in a `List<String>`. I then loop through each of these and create a `PictureBox` for each of them, I then add the same click event to each. The controls are in a `FlowLayoutPanel`

```
foreach(String file in this._files){
    PictureBox box = new PictureBox();
    box.Height = 50;
    box.Width = 50;
    box.ImageLocation = file;
    box.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    box.Click += this.PictureClick;

    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(box);
}

private void PictureClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // how do I get the one that has been clicked and set its border color
}
```

How do I get the one that has been clicked and set its border color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sender` is the `PictureBox` that was clicked:

```
private void PictureClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    PictureBox oPictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    // add border, do whatever else you want.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sender` parameter is indeed your `PictureBox`, downcast to object. Access it this way:

```
var pictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
```

Drawing a border around it could not be so easy as you will have to either override the `OnPaint` method of the PictureBox, either handle the `Paint` event.

You can use this class to draw a black thin border around your image.

```
public class CustomBorderPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public bool BorderDrawn { get; private set; }

    public void ToggleBorder()
    {
        BorderDrawn = !BorderDrawn;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        if (BorderDrawn)
            using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black))
                pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
    }
}
```